# OneSignal Push Notifications to redirect to specific app page

Tags: android, ios, notifications, push, onesignal

Does anybody knows how to direct to a specific app page using OneSignal Push Notification API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To direct users to a specific page, you can use the Additional Data field to add as many key value pairs as you wish. For example, you could add "product_id"="12345".

Next, OneSignal provides a callback function where you can add custom code to receive these key-value pairs when a user clicks a notification. In this function, you can direct the user to the in-app page of your choice.